# Data in ajax call not being passed to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this simple javascript in a Spring MVC with jQuery application:

```
        console.log("POST Variables:",postVariables);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: theUrl,
            traditional: true,
            data: postVariables,
            complete: modelCallback,
            fail : errorFunction
        });
```

the console logs this:

```
POST Variables: applicationId=977
```

Which is correct.  I have this in my controller:

```
public  HashMap<String, Object> getApplication(HttpServletRequest request) {    
    String applicationId = (String) request.getParameter("applicationId");
    logger.error("ApplicationId:"+applicationId);
    Iterator<?> it = request.getParameterMap().keySet().iterator();
    logger.error("Begining parameters:"+request.getParameterMap().keySet().size());
```

This produces null for the String applicationId,  and a 0 for parameter map size.  I originally had the method annotated with @RequestParam,  but that failed and I could not figure out why.  I removed that,  and I see that the ajax call is not sending anything.

I have tried JSON, Javascript Object, and (in this example) a String of request parameters. I have tried with and without the traditional.

I AM using this call inside a callback function from a jQuery get function like this:

```
    $.get(templateUrl).complete(callback);
```

But why is NOTHING getting to my controller?

**UPDATE**  If I change it to a GET,  the parameters are added at the end of the call like they should and everything works fine.

What is even stranger, is that this is in a function, that gets called before, and it works as a POST.  same function.  (different URL and data of course) but SAME function.  Works once, then looks like it fails.  Is there like some socket I need to close?  I grabbing at straws here.

Comment: Did you annotate the Controller Action with: [HttpPost]?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the data to the controller as key value pairs.Not with the equals sign in it.

For example, Not,

```
applicationId=977
```

it should be,

```
applicationId:977
```

add this for the ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: theUrl,
        traditional: true,
        data: {applicationId : "Your application ID as a number"},
        complete: modelCallback,
        fail : errorFunction
});
```

Comment: Makes no difference.

Comment: Did you put the data in two parantheses?